# How to forecast volatility using arch_model.predict() method?

Tags: python, finance, arch

I have fitted a GARCH model using arch library (https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#)
Now I am trying to predict future volatility, but I can't see predictions any further then tomorrow. Changing horizon parameter makes new columns named 'h.' only. What should I do?

```
# Make 100-period ahead forecast
gm_forecast = gm_result.forecast(horizon = 3, method='bootstrap', reindex=False)
#reindex to silence the warning

# Print the forecast variance
print(gm_forecast.mean)
print(gm_forecast.residual_variance)
print(gm_forecast.variance)
```

Output:
h.1       h.2       h.3
Date
2022-05-20  0.230553  0.230553  0.230553
h.1       h.2       h.3
Date
2022-05-20  6.842437  7.512426  7.476012
h.1       h.2       h.3
Date
2022-05-20  6.842437  7.512426  7.476012

Answer (score 0):

The output is fine. You set your `horizon=3`, to predict three timesteps ahead. According to the [docs](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/univariate_volatility_forecasting.html):

> The three main outputs [mean, variance, residual_variance] are all returned in DataFrames with columns of the form h.# where # is the number of steps ahead. That is, h.1 corresponds to one-step ahead forecasts while h.10 corresponds to 10-steps ahead.

That's why you have 3 `h` columns. Please note to predict 100 steps ahead, as your comment suggests to do, you'd need to set `horizon=100`.

**Complete example:**

```py
import datetime as dt
import sys

import arch.data.sp500
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from arch import arch_model

data = arch.data.sp500.load()
market = data["Adj Close"]
returns = 100 * market.pct_change().dropna()

gm_forecast = gm_result.forecast(horizon = 3, method='bootstrap', reindex=False)

gm_forecast.variance
```

**Output:**

```
                h.1       h.2       h.3
Date                                   
2018-12-31  3.59647  3.561266  3.504606
```